# Test htaccess code offline

Tags: .htaccess, offline

I wanted to test my website offline, but this is my problem:

How can I test

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

offline?

Comment: What do you mean with "testing it offline"?

Comment: @Diego I mean `seeing the result on my computer, and that it's not accessible for others`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, all you have to do is make sure that the name of your website points to your local PC/Server. Here's how to do it in OSX, with the following assumptions:
- You will be pointing to your local machine, with address **127.0.0.1**
- Your domain name is **yourdomain.com**.
Replace the above with appropriate values.

**How to edit the host file in OSX**

1. Open the Terminal
2. Edit the host file by typing `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`
3. Add a line containing `127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com`
4. Add a line containing `127.0.0.1 www.yourdomain.com`
5. Save the hosts file
6. Empty the DNS cache by running the command `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Now, every time you try to open yourdomain.com, it will try to connect to your local machine. To undo the above, simply open the file again and comment out (or delete) the lines you added, then flush the DNS cache.

Comment: Then if I go to `yourdomain.com` I will see the website and others won't?

Comment: If you go to yourdomain.com you'll go to your local machine. Every other address will work as usual. The file simply takes priority in name resolution. When you type a domain name, OSX will first check the file. If there's an entry for that domain name, it will go to the address you specified. If not, it will ask a DNS Server to resolve it and go to the address it gives back.

Comment: I do this but use the convention that I end my test entries in `.home`, e.g. `www.yourdomain.home`.  and if you do need to pick up the host you can always use a pattern like `(www\.yourdomain\.(?:com|home))` which returns the domain in %1.  This also makes doing side-by-side comparisons of the current live and test a _lot_ easier.