# How to test .htaccess offline?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess that need to be tested. I can not put it on the server as it may cause the website to crash. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014755/test-htaccess-code-offline) but did not get it. I also used [htaccess tester website](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) but although the htaccess works on this website, it does not work on my server; therefore, need to test it offline.

Comment: Why not test it in a subfolder? Otherwise, you will need to setup a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to make a subdomain and test it in that. In this way you would not have any issues with the current website and no need to have a separate server.

Answer (score 2):

Create an identical copy of your "production" server, hosted on a different server. It can be your localhost, or another "staging" server. So it's not "off line"; rather, it's just not publicly accessible. Once the changes pass your tests in this staging area (aka user-acceptance test server), the changes can be promoted to the production environment. The final ingredient is to be sure you can quickly rollback to the previous version if there are any issues once you do rollout these changes; also, you should of course promote these changes during a  period of low activity.